# SQL query to group a table into table of tables?

Tags: sql, string, group-by, powerbi, pivot

I'm in the middle of "translating" Power BI queries into SQL queries. One of the key queries does the following:

1. Takes the following table:

```
+-----+-----+----------+
| PID | FID | Quantity |
+-----+-----+----------+
| 1   | A   | 15       |
+-----+-----+----------+
| 1   | B   | 2        |
+-----+-----+----------+
| 2   | B   | 3        |
+-----+-----+----------+
| 2   | D   | 8        |
+-----+-----+----------+
| 3   | C   | 2        |
+-----+-----+----------+
```

2. Group by PID, keeping all rows (each `Data` is a table):

```
+-----+-------+
| PID | Table |
+-----+-------+
| 1   | Data  |
+-----+-------+
| 2   | Data  |
+-----+-------+
| 3   | Data  |
+-----+-------+
```

3. Runs some custom logic/manipulation (some of which are very complicated, so not just `COUNT` or `MAX`, etc.) per `Data`, and turns each `Data` into a new table per row:

```
+-----+-------+-------------+
| PID | Table | Transformed |
+-----+-------+-------------+
| 1   | Data  | Data        |
+-----+-------+-------------+
| 2   | Data  | Data        |
+-----+-------+-------------+
| 3   | Data  | Data        |
+-----+-------+-------------+
```

4. Expand the `Transformed` column:

```
+-----+----------------+----------------+
| PID | ResultColumn-1 | ResultColumn-2 |
+-----+----------------+----------------+
| 1   | SomeResult-1   | SomeResult-1b  |
+-----+----------------+----------------+
| 2   | SomeResult-2   | SomeResult-2b  |
+-----+----------------+----------------+
| 3   | SomeResult-3   | SomeResult-3b  |
+-----+----------------+----------------+
```

Is this procedure possible to do in SQL? I was thinking we could use `Group By` with some custom function, but not entirely sure how to go about doing that - any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

---

Sample Output:

```
+-----+------------------+----------------+
| PID | ResultColumn-1   | ResultColumn-2 |
+-----+------------------+----------------+
| 1   | There are 2 of B | and 15 of A    |
+-----+------------------+----------------+
| 2   | There are 8 of D | and 3 of B     |
+-----+------------------+----------------+
| 3   | There are 2 of C |                |
+-----+------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: "*each Data is a table*" - that doesn't make sense. A "table" can't be contained in a query result. The way you have presented the data indicates that "data" is actually a **column** value, not "a table". Your choice of wording makes this very hard to understand. Could you please create a real example using `create table` and `insert into` statements?

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I was explaining this in the context of what PowerQuery was doing. In Power Query a "column value" can be a table. Translating this functionality over to SQL is what I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    pid,
    max(case when rn = 1 then concat('There are ', quantity, ' of ', fid) end) res1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then concat('And ', quantity, ' of ', fid) end) res2
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by pid order by fid desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by pid
```

Note that this assumes not more than 2 rows per `pid`, as shown in your data. Otherwise you would probably need to expand the `select` clause with more conditional expressions.

Comment: Interesting - I never understood `PARTITION BY`. How would your query handle the case where there is only 1 row per pid?

Comment: @Schteeb: if there is only one row this generates the result you showed for pid 3. You can run the subquery independently to see the result it produces and better understand the query.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible using `JOIN` to join between them, and then you can group your results or do further process on them.

Your initial query would be something like :

```
SELECT 
    PID 
,   Table 
,   Transformed 
,   ResultColumn-1
,   ResultColumn-2
FROM 
    table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.PID = t1.PID 
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.PID = t1.PID 
LEFT JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.PID = t1.PID
```

That is if the `PID` Is primary key which is used as a foreign key in the other tables.

If you provided the expected results, then we can give you an initial query that would produce it, which you can use as a kick-starter !

Comment: Thanks for this! What are table1, table2, etc. in your example? I have also added some sample output. Essentially reversing the grouped results, and add some text around it.

Comment: @Schteeb table1 .. 4 are just examples of what you've already provided. (e.g. Table1 is the first example PID, FID, Quantity). The sample output is somewhat needs to be clarified, how to identify in which `ResultColumn-x` is FID under? in your sample, it's clear how you want it, but the business logic behind grouping the results is not clear.